# Why do I get "null" as the JSON string from this bit of kotlin programming, a callback from a successful GPS location report?

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, callback, gson

Expected string here would be: `{ "dateTimeStamp" : "This is the timestamp", "latitude" : 3.14159, "longitude" : 2.718281828 }.`

```
private val mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
        data class LocationReport(val dateTimeStamp : String, val latitude : Double, val longitude : Double)

        val report = LocationReport("This is the timestamp", 3.14159, 2.718281828)
        val jsonReport : String = myHandle.toJson(report)

        messageText.text = jsonReport
    }
}
```

Very similar code worked as expected when called from the top level `onCreate` routine.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 
    class LocationReport(var dateTimeStamp : String, var latitude : Double, var longitude : Double)
    {
        override fun toString() : String {
            return "Time stamp: " + dateTimeStamp +
                   ", latitude: " + latitude.toString() +
                   ", longitude: " + longitude.toString()
        }
    }

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val gson = Gson()
        val report = LocationReport("24-May-2020 8:15 AM PDT", 37.422, -122.084)
        val jsonReport: String = gson.toJson(report)

        messageText.text = jsonReport
    }
}
```

String here would be: `{ "dateTimeStamp" : "24-May-2020 8:15 AM PDT", "latitude" : 37.422, "longitude" : -122.084 }.`

I have searched on the internet with no success.  I tried the `@SerializedName` decorator with no success.  I tried making my class **Parcelable** with no success.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated

Comment: Could Gson be having trouble with the class that’s local to the function? Not sure how that changes how it’s compiled in bytecode, but the accessibility could be different than with the inner class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; that does appear to fix it.  Putting the class declaration at the beginning of the class MainActivity does give me a populated JSON string.

Problem is the class should be declared where it is used, not 100 lines of program away.

In any case you have addressed my problem.  Thank you for your answer!